# SQL Server Trigger INSTEAD OF INSERT to Set Timestamps Before Commit

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql

In SQL Server 2008 R2, I am looking to create a trigger that imitates the behavior of an Oracle `BEFORE INSERT` trigger, where any insert that comes in has the trigger update the UPDATE_TS and CREATE_TS to the current timestamp right before the persist.

To issue I am seeing right now is the error:
  An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MY_TABLE' can only be specified when   a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON

I am not sure if it is a good idea to turn SET IDENTITY INSERT table ON and then 
SET IDENTITY INSERT table OFF within the trigger. Maybe that is a possible solution.

Please advise on best practice.

Example Table is called MY_TABLE:

```
CREATE TABLE [myschema].[MY_TABLE](
[MY_TABLE_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FIELD_TO_UPDATE] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,
[CREATE_TS] [datetime] NULL,
[UPDATE_TS] [datetime] NULL),
PRIMARY KEY (MY_TABLE_ID))
```

Trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_create_ts_trigger 
ON [mydb].myschema.MY_TABLE
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE([MY_TABLE_ID], [FIELD_TO_UPDATE], [CREATE_TS], [UPDATE_TS])
    SELECT i.MY_TABLE_ID, i.FIELD_TO_UPDATE, GETDATE(), GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED as i
END
```

Comment: Instead of a trigger why not put a default of GETDATE() on the column?

Comment: @PreetSangha True, that would be the best option

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not sure why you are using dynamic SQL, it's not really needed. Also, no need to do an `UPDATE` afterwards, you can just do:

```
CREATE TRIGGER my_table_create_ts_trigger 
ON [mydb].myschema.MY_TABLE
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO MY_TABLE(<list of every non identity column here>)
    SELECT <list of every non identity column and the date here>, GETDATE()
    FROM INSERTED

END
```

Also, you should list the columns explicitely in the `INSERT` and the `SELECT`.

Comment: This results in: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MY_TABLE' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: @user2763514 Well, you didn't actually said what columns do `MY_TABLE` has. If it has an `IDENTITY` column (and the error says that it does), then you need to remove it from the column list

Comment: This does not work because removing an identity column from the list breaks the autogenerates coming from the application.

Comment: @aruuuuu hm?, not sure what you mean, this does works. If you are generating the identity on the application, then you shouldn't be using an `IDENTITY` column, just use the value generated by your app (Though I do recommend that the app don't generate that value and that you use an `IDENTITY` column instead)

Comment: I cannot use the value generated from the app without turning SET IDENTITY INSERT table ON and then OFF at the end of the trigger. Is that a safe thing to do?

Comment: If the values for that column will **always** come from the app, why use `IDENTITY` on the first place?. How would I know if it's safe in your case?, is the app making sure that the value doesn't exist first?, how is it managing multiple inserts?, what about concurrency?. That's why I said that you should just use the `IDENTITY` column and not use an app to generate it

Comment: The app is making sure the value does not exist in the first place, and hibernate manages this. There is no issue with generation of identities. All I am seeing is that in the trigger when I am trying to insert does not work because of a constraint violation and that trying to pass the INSERTED.MY_TABLE_ID as a valueinthe INSERT on the trigger throws error error: An explicit value for the identity column in table 'MY_TABLE' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON. Is that enough information? Please let me know if you need to know anything else about my setup.

Comment: @aruuuuu You haven't told me **why** then you are using an `IDENTITY` column if the app is giving the values. But, alas, if you want to insert that, then you need to add on the trigger the `SET IDENTITY INSERT ON`, do the `INSERT` and then add `SET IDENTITY INSERT OFF`.

Answer (score 3):

I must be a glutton for punishment, but I have a better suggestion. **Drop the trigger**.

Change your table to:

```
CREATE TABLE [myschema].[MY_TABLE](
[MY_TABLE_ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[FIELD_TO_UPDATE] [varchar](255) NOT NULL,

-- change this column to have a default:
[CREATE_TS] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,

-- and this column too, I guess:
[UPDATE_TS] [datetime] NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),

PRIMARY KEY (MY_TABLE_ID))
```

Why would you allow those columns to be NULL? Why do you want to use an elaborate trigger to replace something that is much simpler to implement with a default constraint?

You don't need the trigger, and I don't understand what benefit it brings or why you want to replicate a BEFORE trigger. An INSTEAD OF trigger is similar, but not exactly the same thing.

Comment: Aaron u the man. I have added the DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP to one table and it works perfectly.

Comment: Hey Aaron, I tried actually to alter the columns for UPDATE_TS and CREATE_TS ALTER TABLE [myschema].MY_TABLE ADD CONTRAINT create_ts_constraint DEFUALT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FOR CREATE_TS , and also ALTER TABLE [myschema].MY_TABLE ADD CONTRAINT update_ts_constraint DEFUALT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP FOR UPDATE_TS but for some reason the timestamp for update does not get a defualt value on persist. The first timestamp does. Do you know why that is?